# AWS lTelerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau HTTP/1.1" 404 196?

Tags: .net, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, telerik, ddos

I'm using AWS elastickbeanstalk but my site keeps getting hacked, before it was DDOS I fixed that.  now its something else wondering if someone can take a look at this log and see something I cant. I see that it is getting accessed by something called Telerik not sure what this is but, I did a search and it said it was a vulnerability that caused Remote code execution. What every the outcome is it removed my wsgi file that Django/Python needs to talk to httpd on Linux/Apache2 server. any insight would be helpful.

```
-------------------------------------
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:05:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:05:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:05:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:05:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:06:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:06:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:06:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:06:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
**172.31.8.40 (128.14.133.58) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:06:42 +0000] "GET /Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"**
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:07:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:07:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:07:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:07:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:08:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:08:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:08:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:08:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:09:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:09:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:09:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:09:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:10:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:10:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:10:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:10:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:11:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:11:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:11:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:11:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
**209.17.97.10 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:11:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nimbostratus-Bot/v1.3.2; http://cloudsystemnetworks.com)"**
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:12:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:12:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:12:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:12:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:13:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:13:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:13:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:13:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:14:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:14:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:14:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:14:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:15:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:15:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:15:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:15:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:16:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:16:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:16:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:16:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:17:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:17:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:17:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:17:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:18:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:18:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:18:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:18:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (193.169.254.103) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:18:45 +0000] "GET /core/Database/.env HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)"
172.31.36.22 (193.169.254.103) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:18:59 +0000] "GET /apps/.env HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows 98)"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:19:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:19:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:19:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:19:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:20:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:20:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (74.82.47.2) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:20:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "-"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:20:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:20:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:21:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:21:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:21:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:21:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:22:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:22:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:22:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:22:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:23:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:23:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:23:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:23:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:24:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:24:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:24:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:24:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:25:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:25:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:25:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:25:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:26:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:26:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:26:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:26:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (172.58.43.75, 108.162.246.134) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:26:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "https://mostpowerfulcountries.com/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=da5770049b8952476d2c43ef1b9167b86fce0c68-1598333202-0-ASRlvjwAGwlCZGKYCkbXQYeLuP2dHTJzuNstfoiw2fsz-8leDHV0nfdOrUMOjItgAGwBnCsxDsBDOlJ_k7bAmPmFwa9fCq3uTEqHmQAIKrzzuKndoLxN_NW-3ozJ1oloVoNl-N4LzCOcMAWefWiR9ppy7jGM1T7rL0NdxndQNxyTUb3XMtFXC2EWMtYiZ5NDXyWnyw1e031BPQs9k2zCcs1wKWTCHHv3a9lGeYCFja8OWyXPqQq1eDO1sCdYkaDb1oQADMoJisocwTQQvCoGuS0" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:27:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:27:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:27:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:27:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.8.40 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:28:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.36.22 (-) - - [25/Aug/2020:05:28:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

To protect your app from the known vulnerabilities, you have to upgrade the Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX (Telerik.Web.UI.dll) to version R1 2020 (2020.1.114) or later and apply the recommended security settings:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="Telerik.AsyncUpload.ConfigurationEncryptionKey" value="YOUR-FIRST-UNIQUE-STRONG-RANDOM-VALUE-UNIQUE-TO-YOUR-APP&" />
        <add key="Telerik.Upload.ConfigurationHashKey" value="YOUR-SECOND-UNIQUE-STRONG-RANDOM-VALUE-UNIQUE-TO-YOUR-APP&" />
        <add key="Telerik.Upload.AllowedCustomMetaDataTypes" value="Telerik.Web.UI.AsyncUploadConfiguration" />
</appSettings>
```

You can see how to generate the security keys on

[Generate security keys for RadAsyncUpload (Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX). Prevent CVE-2019-18935 and CVE-2017-11317](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J18zDKtiBFE)

The following articles provide more information too:

- https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/allows-javascriptserializer-deserialization
- https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/upload-(async)/details/unrestricted-file-upload
- https://www.telerik.com/blogs/blue-mockingbird-vulnerability-telerik-guidance
- https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/asyncupload/security#recommended-settings